# Kotlin operadores, funciones

Tags: funciones, kotlin, variables, operador

Hola estoy programando en Kotlin y cuando creas variables hay veces que le pones `!!` , `?` a las variables. ¿Para qué sirven estos operadores?

Tambien hay veces en que le pones `let`, `apply`, `run`, `with`, `also`. ¿Para qué sirven estos?

Gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Te puede servir la documentación oficial: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types

Comment: Y esta es la sección sobre las scope functions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html